# To pass id and name through javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]
The output shown on image

Hi am not much expertise in javascript, In my code I have Add-Items & Delete-Items button which is working fine.First row works fine for total calculation function but rest of rows not working because of that Am not able to assign different names and ids for created row. How I can reuse javascript. Also please let me know how to receive data on submit using POST method or this code and how to find total amount of all rows I inserted at the bottom of table.
Thanks in Advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="add_rows.js"></script> 
        <script>
            function func()
            {
                var w = document.getElementById("qty").value;
                var x = document.getElementById("price").value;
                var z = document.getElementById("total");
                z.value = Number(w)*Number(x);
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
      <fieldset class="row2">
                <legend>Catering Order Details</legend>
                <p> 
                    <input type="button" value="Add Items" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Remove Items" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 
                </p>

            <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <p>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Item</label>
                            <select size="1" name="Item[]" required="required" > 
                            <?php
                                echo "<option value=''>---Choose Item---</option>";
                                $q=mysqli_query($dbConnect1,"SELECT DISTINCT ITEM as Item, ITEM_ID FROM `manage_item`");
                                while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
                                {
                                $i=$r['ITEM_ID'];
                                $n=$r['Item'];
                                echo "<option value='$i'> $n</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label>Quantity</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required"  name="Qty[]" id="qty" value="">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label>Price/Quantity</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required"  name="Price[]" id="price" value="" onChange="func()">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label>Total</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required"  name="Total[]" id="total" value="">
                         </td>
                            </p>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my script

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 100){                     
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximum items is 100.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {                         
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Items.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: give every row a unique ID based on count and bind the event.

Comment: function func(i)
            {
                var w = document.getElementById("qty_"+i).value;
                var x = document.getElementById("price_"+i).value;
                var z = document.getElementById("total_"+i);
                z.value = Number(w)*Number(x);
            }

Comment: Hi, every row is added dynamically here by clicking add Item button. When this event is triggered how to pass id and name from javascipt so that it has to populate that in new row which is added.

Comment: by input element event

Answer (score 1):

Instead to use IDs you may change them to class names like in:

```
<input type="text" required="required"  name="Qty[]" class="qty" value="" oninput="func(this)">
```

Because you are using inline events you can:

> - use [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event because the DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an <input>, <select>, or <textarea> element is changed.

- **this** as parameter to the inline function: it will be the current element

Hence, change your **func** to:

```
function func(ele) {
    var parentRow = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
    var w = parentRow.querySelector('input.qty').value;
    var x = parentRow.querySelector('input.price').value;
    var z = parentRow.querySelector('input.total');
    z.value = Number(w)*Number(x);
}
```

The **this** parameter now is the **ele**, current element. You can now get the parent row and using the classes and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you can find all elements.

The snippet:

```js
function updateGrandTotal() {
    var gt = document.querySelector('input.grantotal');
    gt.value = 0;
    document.querySelectorAll('input.total').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
        gt.value = +gt.value + +ele.value;
    });
}
function func(ele) {
    var parentRow = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
    var w = parentRow.querySelector('input.qty').value;
    var x = parentRow.querySelector('input.price').value;
    var z = parentRow.querySelector('input.total');
    z.value = Number(w)*Number(x);
    updateGrandTotal();
}
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length -1;
    if(rowCount < 100){
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount + 1);
        var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
        alert("Maximum items is 100.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Items.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    updateGrandTotal();
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="row2">
  <legend>Catering Order Details</legend>
  <p>
      <input type="button" value="Add Items" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
      <input type="button" value="Remove Items" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  />
  </p>

  <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
              <label>Grand Total</label>
              <input type="text" required="required"  name="Total[]" class="grantotal" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
          <p>
          <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" /></td>
          <td>
              <label>Item</label>
              <select size="1" name="Item[]" required="required" >
                  <option value=''>---Choose Item---</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
              </select>
          </td>
          <td>
              <label>Quantity</label>
              <input type="text" required="required"  name="Qty[]" class="qty" value="" oninput="func(this)">
          </td>
          <td>
              <label>Price/Quantity</label>
              <input type="text" required="required"  name="Price[]" class="price" value="" oninput="func(this)">
          </td>
          <td>
              <label>Total</label>
              <input type="text" required="required"  name="Total[]" class="total" value="">
          </td>
          </p>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi gaetanoM thanks its working fine.. Is there any way to get total amount of all rows and display in bottom. Also on submit of this data how I came to know that how many rows are added to push the data in database.

Comment: @JagannathB In order to get total amount I added a function **updateGrandTotal**. For the second part of your comment you may wrap your table in a form or ajax all the inputs, then you need to implement a server side code. Thanks